# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have this exception with mybatis

> --- Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
> --- The error occurred in sqlMaps/WorkSession.xml.
> --- The error occurred while applying a result map.
> --- Check the getChangeSeller-AutoResultMap.
> --- Check the result mapping for the 'IS_RESTRICTED' property.
> --- Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData

And this is my sqlMap workSession.getChangeSeller :

```
<select id="getChangeSeller" parameterMap="getChangeSellerParam" resultClass="Boolean">
      
  select decode(count(*),0,0,1) is_restricted
        from users u inner join user_sdp us on u.user_id = us.user_id 
        inner join sdp s on s.sdp_id = us.sdp_id
        where u.user_id = ? and s.sdp_id = ? and s.self_cash_cycle_only = 1 and u.self_cash_cycle_only =1

</select>
```

Comment: You have version mismatches with your dependencies somewhere.

Comment: I am using ojdbc 7 , ibatis-2.3.0 and jdk 7.

Comment: @kh123 Post the entire stack trace, please.

Comment: Actually, it is worse than just a version mismatch.  It looks to me like you have two copies of the same type ... which means that the class has been loaded by two separate classloaders.  My guess is that you have the Oracle driver in both the web container's (i.e. weblogic's) shared library folder and in a webapp's WAR file.  Or something like that.  (But I'm not familiar with MyBatis ....)